# iOS App Store: Complete my bundle option missing

Tags: ios-appstore

I have previously benefited from [complete my bundle](https://support.apple.com/HT201162) feature available in the App Store. I was able to get newer apps that I haven't purchased at a discounted rate.

I am looking to purchase an app now and could not find the option on the apps App Store page.

[image] [image]

My question is:

- Is the feature no longer available for apps (and only available for Songs and TV Shows)?
- Is it upto the developers discretion to incorporate complete my bundle feature?

Comment: [The post at this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/7bvfab/complete_my_bundle_pricing_appears_to_be_gone_in/) at Reddit alludes to the removal of the discount pricing, and perhaps even the bundling feature, after the release of iOS 11. The Apple Support doc you reference is vague.  [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-bundles/) still has the generic page up without any iOS 11 qualifications.

Comment: I was told it’s a developer option that they can offer or not offer.  I have no further information.

Comment: @IconDaemon Thanks for the helpful reply. However, it couldn't help us come to a conclusive yes/no answer (which I am looking for).